# Cache POST response from a System.Web.Http.ApiController

Tags: ajax, caching, asp.net-apicontroller

I have a `System.Web.Http.ApiController` that performs 'calculations' and it knows how to do its own server side caching.  I would like to enable caching so that the browser returns 302 and the response is returned from the browser cache.

Unfortunately, I have to perform a POST, mostly because the size of the payload is to big to reasonably fit as a query string parameter (it could exceed the max length - very unlikely, but possible).

The logic of when the cache refreshes is more than just the 'input' coming into the request.  Part of the logic to clear the cache is dependent on whether or not the currently logged in user's data has changed...and this might occur on a different page.  Therefore, implementing a purely client side 'sessionStorage' type cache would be tricky.  I have some ideas, but in addition to cache busting logic, I'm (maybe naively) worried about the amount of data that could be stored in the sessionStorage and getting a bulletproof mechanism on clearing the storage when needed, etc.

Therefore, I'm hoping to just leverage browser caching and a status code of `302`.  However, right now, I'm simply using `$ajax` and `method: "POST"` in the configuration.

I think if I am performing a `GET`, I could do something like:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "/url?withQueryString=true",
    cache: true,
    headers: { 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0' }
}) ... ;
```

And on the server,

```cs
// Psuedo code, but more or less correct...
var requestIfModified = context.Request.Headers.Get( "If-Modified-Since" );
var lastModifiedDate = DateTime.Today; // This would be my 'date' representing when cache was valid

if ( requestIfModified >= lastModifiedDate.AddMilliseconds( -lastModifiedDate.Millisecond ) )
{
    // Set status = NotModified;
    // return;
}

// else, no cache hit...

// Set response cache last modified = lastModifiedDate
// Set response cache max age = new TimeSpan( 0, 0, 0 )
// Set response cache expires = 'now'

// return 'new' calculation result
```

However, as you might have guessed, in the client side code `$.ajax(requestConfig).then( (response, status, jqXHR) => ... )`, `status` = 'notmodified' but both the `response` and `jqXHR.responseJSON` are `undefined`.

I'm hoping there is a way around this problem?  I'm fearing that it is because `$.ajax` is ignoring my headers because of `POST`?  Can I submit `POST` another way?